# Google Maps returning error 610

Tags: google-maps

I had a google maps v3 application working for about a year now without any problems.  The application uses two different methods to geocode an address, when I geocode using the google maps javascript everything works.   I also geocode with a c# page, I request geocoding through a url.  I get error 610 using the URL method.

Here is the URL I am using:http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=64108&key=KEY

Did you URL change? should i be using something different?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google has officially deprecated support for API v2 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/

You have to change your lookup: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index

```
Example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=64108&sensor=false
```

And you don't need to use the key anymore, do note the limit has been changed to 2500

This article from Google shows how to upgrade from version 2 to 3:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodingupgrade

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info. I'll just add that http:// works as well as https://

Answer (score 0):

Error 610 suggests a invalid API key (key is invalid or domain is wrong).

You can generate one here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

Comment: I opened all the keys up to accept anything, and I am using the same key that works in javascript.  Do you know the URL to geocode an address?